# I can't program my uC. Avrdude throws error which I don't understand

Tags: atmega, microprocessors, avrdude

I used to programing my uCu before but now I have very weird error. It seems to be problem with programmer but I'm not sure. Avrdude throws this error:
***C:\Users\Adam>avrdude -p m328p -c avrispmkII
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\com1": The system cannot find the file specified.***

and atmel studio this

***Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)
Unable to enter programming mode. Verify device selection, interface settings, target power, security bit, and connections to the target device***

I have tried use different ports but it didn't help. Device Menager said I already have good driver. Please help me find the solution.

**This is  a picture of my circuit**
[image]

Comment: USBASP works fine. It has to be the problem with programer( avrispmkII)

Comment: Are you sure it is on COM1? Do you see it in the device manager?

Comment: I have tried all ports

Comment: did you check continuity on all your connections? breadboards are very errorprone.

Comment: your picture did not include the programmer